# symfony parameters.yml float

Tags: symfony, parameters

I don't understand how to register float value in the parameters.yml file.

I tried to add :

```
parameters:
    euro: 1,0
    dollar: 1,14
    sterling: 1,20
```

After, I run "composer update" and the result is :

```
parameters:
    euro: !!float 10
    dollar: !!float 114
    sterling: !!float 120
```

So, I think something is wrong, right ?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Already tried to write float with a dot instead of a comma, like 1.0 not 1,0 ?

Comment: No/Yes, I thougth that if composer detect that with comma is a float, probably a point will not run correctly. I will try and give feedback. Thanks :)

Comment: You're right it works fine with a point. Thanks :)

Comment: In general float are with **.** not **,** :)

Answer (score 0):

Use dot like this:

```
parameters:
euro: 1.0
dollar: 1.14
sterling: 1.20
```